# yeoman installation issue: command not found

Tags: yeoman

I tried to install yeoman on my machine - Linux system.

I follow the instructions from [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/), which told me so:

`npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`

After that, I tried it and an error occured: `yeoman command not found`.

I google some about this, some say that the `/usr/share/local/npm/bin` should be put to global Path. However, I don't have such a path, no `/usr/share/local/npm`.

Any help ?

Answer (score 5):

`yeoman` is not the binary; it's simply `yo`.

Keep reading the Getting Started Guide (http://yeoman.io/learning/) :)

Comment: I've seen several books or blogs telling me that to use "yeoman init","yeoman server", are these out of date ?

Comment: Yep! Yeoman is nearing 1.0. Several months ago, 0.9.x had the "yeoman ___" workflow.

Comment: but still both yo and yeoman do not work. still get command not found error. exhausting :(